Predictive Aim to shoot a moving target with a constant velocity while the projectile is affected by gravity (2D/Platformer view)
I've been working on creating stationary gun turrets that can shoot down missiles in my game. The bullets are affected by gravity while the missile moves in a linear path at a constant rate as if it had no acceleration or gravity.


My math is most likely wrong because it doesnt work even after I've tweaked and changed a few things.
Could someone please explain the derivation of the correct formula?

Does this answer your question? How do I launch a ballistic projectile to hit a moving target, given: launch position & angle, target position & velocity?

Does this answer your question? How do I launch a ballistic projectile to hit a moving target, given: launch position & angle, target position & velocity?

See also https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74282/aim-at-moving-target-or-predicting-targets-position-at-time-it-takes-for-proje
If you're unsure about formulas you've written about paper, your question probably belongs on the Physics Stack Exchange. If you've actually written code, you'd get better help by sharing the code you wrote (after all, your code might have mistakes that aren't in the original math). But with a little searching you should be able to find many solutions to this problem.

ill be checking out physics stack exchange as Im sure it's the formulas I've written. Thanks for the other sources also.

Please note that the norm here is to post formulas & code as formatted text rather than images. More info can be found in our guides for general formatting and math formatting. I suspect the Physics SE may have similar norms.
